# Wicket - Browser Back Button

Tags: spring, wicket

I have a web application that uses Apache Wicket. After the submitting of a form, I need to intercept the browser's back button, in order to redirect to the initial page, or to a expired page. How can I implement this? I try with

```
@Override 
protected void setHeaders(WebResponse response) { 
           response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
          response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store"); 

   }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: The above code by default wicket will handle You don't need to call explicitly .

Comment: Ok, but for me doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure . may be page version set to false  other case may be Your page  stateless page .

Comment: Can you add page version on form also because form not page version by default

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to add page version on form also .

Pages are versioned by default but Forms are not. If you want to make a form versioned call form.setVersioned(true) on the form right after all components have been added (not before).

For more [check here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Versioning)

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple javascript code to the response. "history.back();". This javascript code forcing browser to do BACK function

Comment: where you will give `history.back()`? what if i use  right click and say back ?